# Calculate Distance in Km and Miles

Tags: distance, latitude-longitude

I have two points whose latitude and longitude i know.

How can i calculate the distance(in Km and Miles) between them. What is the formulae?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to calculate such distances.

Answer (score 3):

Use the haversine Formula for this...

Here is the link having java script code to calculate distance

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 2):

```
   A = LAT1, B = LONG1
   C = LAT2, D = LONG2 (all converted to radians: degree/57.29577951)

   IF A = C AND B = D THEN DISTANCE = 0; 
   ELSE

     IF [SIN(A)SIN(C)+COS(A)COS(C)COS(B-D)] > 1 THEN DISTANCE = 3963.1*ARCOS[1]; 

     ELSE

      DISTANCE=3963.1*ARCOS[SIN(A)SIN(C)+COS(A)COS(C)COS(B-D)];
```

Answer (score 1):

For an accurate and complete (works with any pair of points) solution
use my geodesic calculator at
http://geographiclib.sf.net/cgi-bin/GeodSolve.  The formulas are given in
http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.1215.