# How to create a grid overlay of earth? (I.e., ignoring the circular shape of earth when calculate coordinates)

Tags: google-maps, gis

I am working with an application that dumps the latitude/longtitude coordinates into my database. My goal is to apply a grid layout to the earth (using Google Maps), group the coordinates together and update the correct grid cell. However, I am stuck with regards to how to create the grid overlay.

All the formulas I have found (for example [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) or the Google Maps computeOffset) take the earths shape into consideration. When using these formulas to calculate the coordinates for the grid cells, the lines naturally becomes skewed as the distance increases. My question is therefore, is there a formula for calculating latitude/longtitude that ignores the shape of the earth (where the input is a set of coordinates, bearing and length in meters)? I.e., what I want to achieve is:

If I have a point (0,0) and I want to find the position that is 100m to the east, I want the formula to return (latitude_offset_100m,0). Using a formula which considers the circular shape of the earth, this might give for example (latitude_offset_100m,longtitude_offset_5m).

Comment: Take a look at [Map Projections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection)

Comment: @confused-demon Thank you, I have taken a look at them, however, I have yet to find one that meets my requirement. If you know which one to use, then that would be great.

Comment: sorry, have no ready solution, but I think you can use [haversine formula](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264571/calculate-distance-in-km-and-miles) as a base for your coordinate system. Take point with latlng 0,0 as your zero, using haversine you can translate coordinates from mercator to what you need and vise versa

Comment: @confused-demon Yes, that seems to work as long as the size of the grids is not too large. At least up to ~2km, the grids seems to be fairly aligned.

Comment: you stand at origion, head to east precisely, then close your eye and walk straight 2km: i am sure latitude changes as you walk because of curvature of the earth, and this haversine formula is telling you how much it going to be off.  If you define coordinate based on orthogonal coordinate at the origin and stretch out, it is going to skew as you get far away, and the line of easting no longer points to east.  kind of strange why you want to do it.  earth is rounded even though we dont want it sometimes.

Comment: @yosukesabai It is mostly a cosmeti issue, however, I also got interested just in if it was possible to solve. Nice straight lines looks better than skewed lines.

Comment: Cosmetics in terms of how they look in x,y table, or how they look when shown on map?  If you dont care how coodinates in lat/lon comes and only care how they look on map, there should be way to find one that is acceptallbly close (i still have to look for it).  But I am concerned cuz you said you dont like "position that is 100m to the east ..." turns out to be "(latitude_offset_100m,longtitude_offset_5m)"  I dont think you can change that, because that's how latitude, longitude are defined.

Comment: @yosukesabai Yes, only for drawing on the map, the actual coordinates will only be mapped to a specific cell. I think using haversine should be ok, as the line appears to be fairly straight for shorter distances. I agree you can't change how lat/long works, but I was wondering if there was a projection which did not consider  or corrected for the shape of the earth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to achieve what I wanted. By using [rhumb lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhumb_line), you can get "straight" lines on a Mercator projected map (like Google maps).